# How do I display text at 60pt or even 600pt?

Tags: fontsize

I am new to LaTeX. I am having a hard time creating a font past 40 points. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont hi
\end{document}
```

If I change the 40 and corresponding 48 to anything bigger, it does not seem to increase the size of the word "hi". I can go lower but not higher.

Technically I need this for some text in a cell for a table I am working on in LaTeX, but I'm sure if I figured out what I was doing wrong I could apply it to the table. The font size I am aiming for is somewhere around 60 to 100 points in size.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** I added a new example to compare scaled fonts and resized fonts.

LaTeX can't use font sizes that are not listed in the `.fd` file. When compiling your MWE, you can see some warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <40> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 8.
```

because the `.fd` file of Computer Modern provides a discrete list of sizes (with a maximum size of 24.88pt).

To use scalable fonts, there are some useful packages:

- `type1cm` (Computer Modern via cm-super).
- `anyfontsize` (with any font but automatically only via  latex)
- `lmodern`  (a sort of "super cm-super").

Here is an example using `lmodern` package (that provides scalable fonts):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont hi
    \fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont hi
    \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont hi%

    % compare scaled fonts and resized fonts
    \fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont hi%
    \scalebox{5}{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont hi}%
    \scalebox{10}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont hi}%
    \scalebox{20}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont hi}

    % a BIG font
    \fontsize{300}{350}\selectfont hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add why it doesn't work for the default CM fonts?

Comment: How about just adding the `anyfontsize` package?

Comment: It works for CM fonts with package `type1cm` with smoother scaling. The restriction of the standard behaviour comes from the times with PK fonts, where for each size a new PK fonts had to be generated. Using fixed sizes helped to limit the number of PK fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If this does not form part of regular textual content, you can always resize it in a box:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  hi &
  \large hi &
  \Huge hi &
  \resizebox{!}{100pt}{hi} &
  \scalebox{20}{hi}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides the scaling/resizing capability.

Comment: Change the size of a font is not always a homothetic transformation...

Comment: I suggest you read again the third paragraph of chapter 1 of the TeXbook.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: The OP mentions "Technically I need this for some text in a cell for a table" which is small in scale. The examples shown by Paul reflecting the "poor" transformation of text under scaling is a bit extreme: Why would one resize a `5pt` (`\tiny`) font to `100pt` - it is visually obvious that the kerning for `\tiny` is awkward, which is exacerbated when enlarged 20 times. Honestly, I don'y see a loss in quality using the above method, nor the need to switch to a different typesetting system as a result.